# check if input checkbox checked not working

Tags: php, javascript, json

form :

```
<label for="sitecheck">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">סגור אתר זמנית:</span>
</label>
<input name="sitecheck" type="checkbox" id="sitecheck" onClick="validateSitec();" <?php if($data['sclosed'] == 'true'){echo 'checked = "checked"';}; ?> /><span style="font-weight:bold;">סגור אתר ורשום הודעה זמנית</span><br>
<input type="text" name="closedmsg" id="closedmsg" style="width:440px;height:120px;<?php if($data['sclosed'] == 'true'){echo '';}else{ echo 'display:none;'; }; ?>" value="<?php echo $data['csitemsg']; ?>" /><span id="sitemsg_error"></span>
```

php :

```
 if(isset($_POST['sitecheck']))
    {
        $sitecheck = 'true';
    }else{
         $sitecheck = 'false';
    }
```

any idea why its not working ?
i trying to determine if checked or not and update on Database.. anyidea why its alwys true even if i uncheck?

**EDIT :**

fixed by my own was ajax post wrong , i should val the checked box like that :

```
  var sitecheck  = $('#sitecheck').is(':checked') ? $('#sitecheck').val() : '' ;
```

so now working thanks.

Comment: uhm, just to clarify, is the above HTML snippet being wrapped between `<form>` tags ?

Comment: What do JavaScript and JSON have to do with this?

Comment: yea afcours ;0 its just part of the code,i just sned the post via json so to make it clarify

Comment: @user2635001 — You need to provide the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. Don't leave bits out and assume that people answering the question will assume you didn't really forget them and that you got them right.

Comment: What is `validateSitec();` doing? Maybe there is a problem.

Comment: What do you mean "send the post via JSON"? That makes no sense. You might send JSON via a POST request, but not the other way around. If you *are* sending JSON instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, then that would explain why that code isn't working.

Comment: validate just slidedown and up the msg box in javascript , Quentin forget about the type of the post , all working exept this its always true..

Comment: Quentin its have no differnce between json or not , since i send "on" in any type for post request.

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` param to your checkbox. Value will be send if checkbox is checked.

```
 <input name="sitecheck" type="checkbox" id="sitecheck" value="1" ....
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, if there isn't a value attribute, then it will default to `"on"`, which is sufficient to pass the test in the PHP.

Comment: what the diffrence if it just send "on" instead of value ? anyway i will try that way too.

Comment: @user2635001 — Since you are just testing for `isset`: No difference whatsoever, which was my point.